# Poisoned Kitchen Sink?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I wonder…I have a 20 years old stainless kitchen sink in good condition.

“Somebody” poured “Green Gobbler” into the sink. Green Gobbler is a Drain Clog Disolver (supposed to be kitchen sink safe and non-caustic but who knows).

[Product Description](https://greengobbler.com/products/dissolve-liquid-hair-clog-remover)

I cleaned the sink with hot water and soap. Can residual of the “Green Gobbler” be absorbed into the stainless steel and be hazardous, i.e. “poison” the sink?

Thank you!

Comment: In my opinion it should be closed otherwise every fear imagi-marginally related to chemistry can find place here.

Comment: Unless I have missed it, the vendor keeps the composition secret, giving just hints it is based on natural components. It is not possible to give more particular safety advices than the vendor gives.

Comment: I presume the contents are a mixture of hydrolytic enzymes that will digest organic residues in the drain

Comment: Maybe the Green Gobbler might gobble you if poured upon you. Other than that, it is harmless. You can't poison steel like that. You can, however, poison your mind with chemophobia. That's a very real danger. We've seen that happen to people, with lamentable results.

Answer (score 2):

The safety data sheet for this product while not disclosing the actual contents lists them as "non-hazardous". The point about stainless steel is that it has a resistant surface that does not react with much so I think it very unlikely that anything can be absorbed that would then cause harm.

Answer (score 0):

The label says that the substance contains no sodium hydroxide, and no bleach. So it must contain trisodium phosphate $\ce{Na3PO4}$. which is corrosive enough to clean blocked pipes. But this substance is rather soluble in water, and it will not remain or stick on the sink or on the surface of pipes. The sink may be in steel, plastic or ceramics. It will not be modified by sodium triphosphate. The trisodium phosphate should not be swallowed, of course. And it will be slowly destroyed by carbon dioxide $\ce{CO2}$ from the air. A good washing will remove all traces of sodium phosphate. The sink will be clean, but not poisoned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses!